# Why it is not showing string on output screen

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
const int max = 100;
void main()
{
  char output[max];
  string a;
  ofstream veiw("myfile.txt");
  cout << "Enter name: ";
  getline(cin, a);
  veiw << a;
  ifstream get("myfile.txt");
  //it have to show line    
  get.getline(output, max);
  cout << output << endl;
  system("pause");
}
```

[Output Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6FuX.png)

Comment: The file is still held open by `view`. Trying to open it again with `get` most likely fails. I can't help but notice that your code doesn't perform any error checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `veiw.close();` after the line `veiw << a;` should do.

Always remember to close your file after finish using it.

Comment: The codes in comments are not readable... if you want to ask another question, you can ask another question. Instead, you can edit this question to add new informations to it.